# Optimize htaccess Wildcard Subdomain Code

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I have Wildcard Subdomains working perfectly on my server, but would like to optimize the .htaccess code to make it more portable. I'm not sure how to do it.

I would like to replace the **specific domain name and extension** (DOMAIN and .com in the code below) with a regex match so that when using the wildcard code for other domains it is easy to port. *So it should be a drop in replacement for domain.com and domain2.net*. Here's the code I use:

```
# Wildcard Subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([^.]+)\.DOMAIN\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %2 !^www$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://DOMAIN.com/$1?a=%2 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

It's a little different than the usual version you see, because I've added the exception for the www. + subdomain condition. It many cases people enter www.sub.domain.com which breaks on the server. So I check for the www. and remove it before redirecting.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The way you currently have it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www)\.(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteCond %2 !^www$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%3.%4/$1?a=%2 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

If you just want to strip the www from the domain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www)\.(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%2.%3.%4/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```