# Remove wildcard subdomains but not existing ones with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, wildcard, subdomain

**Hello!**

I'm trying to set up my .htaccess file for wildcard subdomains, but I really have no clue how to do that.

I have "domain2" pointing to "domain1" as an alias, which is working perfectly, this is the code I'm using:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www)\.(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%2.%3.%4/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*\.?)domain2.co\.cc$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1domain1.co.cc/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I found the www redirect here btw: [Optimize htaccess Wildcard Subdomain Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207549/optimize-htaccess-wildcard-subdomain-code)

Now, what I want is all non-existent subdomains to get removed and the ones that exist (like "blog.domain1.co.cc" to stay.

I hope someone can help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more details e.g a few examples of what you would like to happen, define which domains exist etc.

Comment: I currently have 2 domains: discussions.domain1.co.cc and www.domain1.co.cc  

Any wildcard subdomains (like asdf.domain1.co.cc) should redirect to www.domain1.co.cc, but existing subdomains (like discussions.domain1.co.cc) should be excluded from this rule.  

examples:  
`asdf.domain1.co.cc/article-2 --> www.domain1.co.cc/article-2  `
`discussions.domain1.co.cc/thread-7 --> discussions.domain1.co.cc/thread-7  `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

#no longer needed
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

#don't redirect blog.example.com, forum.example.com and example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((blog|forum)\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule .* - [L]

#redirect the rest (including www.) to example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Ok, it's not working unfortunately. I just yesterday moved my site to another host, maybe it's because of that.  

Not even the domain alias is working now.  

Could you first help me with that?  

I basically want everything aliased so it redirects subdomains and subdirectories to the other domain, just like that:  

`forum.old.com/thread/12038213 --> forum.new.com/thread/12038213`  
  
I haven't found any thread here that does both.

Comment: Please start a new question about that. Also, we need more info than what you provide in this comment.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It's not urgent, though. I'll ask next year, maybe. Happy Holidays! =)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your htaccess file.

```
#if these lines already exist, skip them
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#if its not www or discussions subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|discussions)\.domain1\.co\.cc$ [NC]
#redirect to www domain
RewriteRule .* http://www.domain1.co.cc%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

For the following question

> redirects subdomains and subdirectories to the other domain, just like that: forum.old.com/thread/12038213 --> forum.new.com/thread/12038213

Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#if domain is old.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.old\.com$ [NC]
#redirect to new.com
RewriteRule .* http://%1.new.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```